# Juniper not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, juniper

I recently upgrade my laptop to windows 8.1 and now I can't run the Juniper terminal to connect to the company VPN. 
At the moment to click on the virtual machine it launche the terminal and afetr a few seconds a messages popup appears saying: **juniper terminal services client has stopped working**

When I had windows 8 I was able to run Juniper without any problem. But in Windows 8.1 seems there are compatibilities issues.

Any suggestion, solution or workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Localised to a bug fix coming up then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Juniper supports knows about the issue](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28018), they will release a fix later this year.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on this site -- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-networking/juniper-vpn-clienti-will-not-connect-in-windows-81/d819ee3b-cb22-4951-b791-52c562cf73e0 -- claims to have a workaround. I'm not trying anything until I know Juniper has an actual solution that is supported by my company.